# how to extract part of href using CSS selector in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, css-selectors, jsoup

```
    <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Modules/Search/Search.aspx?code=ddaed8994a56a0a655976eb64946e861b2d5a5e391d1b62f83e19b3f6b224db4&amp;scope=openid%20api1&amp;state=8048c94b1f804d379fc295732852fdd6&amp;session_state=AI9280sswK6JzNkTRH5pz-sk3aci7S16KuYoiEyzhF0.737be1ce76d0c83a60b3c2c06a45564c&amp;ClientId=webform&amp;AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

In above html response, how can i extract code, scope, session_state value. These values are dynamic in nature. Can someone please help me here. I tried below:
a:contain(code)/a:containsOwn(code)/ a[href*='code']
gives only here as result using above tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use CSS Selector Extractor to extract a part of the [href attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp), you can only get the full value, moreover your syntax is not correct, see [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) article for more details.

I would rather suggest going for [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor), it basically extracts everything between "left" and "right" boundaries so you could do something like:

[image]

More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)

Comment: I did same but did not work out for me. Please note that above html comes as response body of one of login API which is driven by open ID connect. I see still its breaking !

Comment: Try changing "Apply to" to "Main sample and sub-samples"